# Downhill bike frame conundrum

Tags: frames, downhill, new-bicycle-assembly, newbie

So I am starting a bike from scratch and really want a downhill frame as I'll be riding downhills and commuting. How and what parts could I use and add to the frame so it is able to commute though I get the great frame.

Also what are the cons of a downhill frame are they quite heavy? Sorry, I'm really new to this

Comment: Get two bikes. The demands from DH and commuting are so different that your bike ends up being terrible for at least one but probably both.

Comment: If you want to ride downhill then you need downhill wheels, suspension and drivetrain, all of which will make for a terrible commuter - unless your commute is on a downhill trail, going down both ways! On the other hand, maybe you're OK riding a heavy bike with big tires and tons of suspension travel for a few miles on tarmac roads every day.

Comment: Not to forget that DH bikes are never cheap, even used ones. Commuting on a bike means often leaving it unattended at random places for random periods of time. Expensive bikes tend to get stolen more often than cheap ones. Parked bicycles that stand out among surrounding ones (and a "commuter DH bike" will definitely be a white crow) also tend to draw unnecessary attention. All in all, it is more likely to get your expensive toy to get stolen. I prefer to keep my toys locked out of sight, and to reach out for them only when I want to play with them.

Comment: You're best off working on the commuter first.   Buy a used bike and ride it to work.  Figure out what you like and don't.  That will give you more info when speccing your downhill bike.  You can even ride the commuter on some off-road tracks to get more ideas.

Comment: The only way I see a downhill bike being suitable for a commute is either if the commute is very short or if you build an electric DH bike (ebike), the latter will definitely be expensive though. As previously mentioned a DH bike is heavy and therefore will take a lot of effort to pedal (especially uphill).

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that you're not an experienced DH racer - otherwise you wouldn't want to build a "dh commuter", therefore you might be happy with an xc hardtail bike - it can take some descends on rough terrain while can be used as a commuter bike (with some limitations)